# Is the 2-Category of Groupoids Locally Presentable?

Tags: category-theory, groupoids, locally-presentable-categories, accessible-categories

I am wondering if the 2-Category of groupoids is Locally Presentable?  Locally presentable means the category is accessible and co-complete.

Edit:
It has been pointed out that the category of Groupoids is Locally Preseantable.  It would be useful if I could find a theorem that says that if your base category, namely groupoids, was LP, then so is the 2-category on that base.  I have done a bit of research and I cannot find anything to that effect.  I still cannot say if the 2-category of Groupoids is LP.

Comment: The $1$-category of groupoids is the category of models of a limit sketch, so it is locally presentable, but what does it mean for a $2$-category to be locally presentable?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Hi, so I am really not sure.  Are you suggesting that there is no sense in which a 2-category can be locally presentable?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I am now a little sure that a 2 category can be LP.  Is it the case that the 2 cat is LP if the underlying cat is LP: ie, since groupoids is LP the 2-cat of groupoids is LP?